# Insert in many to many relation laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models:

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','name','surname','fathers_name','phone_number','city','post_office','comment'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order_product');
    }

}
```

---

```
class Product extends Model
{

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_product');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

3 tables:

```
product:
id
name
...

order_product:
id
order_id
prod_id
qty
...

order
id
city
phone
...
```

and 2 arrays of data:
$data = $request->except('_token','submit'); - information about client
$order_content - array with info about products in cart

So, the question is how to insert all this data in DB? I tried to read about many to many insertion: sync, attach, etc.. but understood nothing :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a product with id 1. And an order with id 1. The product is part of the order, so you have to attach them. You do

```
$product = Product::find(1);
$order = Order::find(1);
$order->products()->attach($order->id);
```

However, in your case, your pivot table has more data, like 'qty'. Then you do,

```
$order->product()->attach($order->id, ['qty' => 2]);
```

So far, we were only attaching a single product to an order. If you want to attach many products simultaneously, you do:

```
$order->products()->sync([
    $product->id => ['qty' => 1],
    $product2->id => ['qty' => 3]
]);
```

I hope this helps understand better. I recommend you read the doc again and again until it makes sense.

Comment: Its strange, but in the order_product im getting only last product of 3 in the  order

Comment: Thats what im doing:
$order = (new Order)->create($data);
$cart_content = Cart::content();
        $order_content = [];

        foreach($cart_content as $key=>$cart_item) {

            $order_content[$key]['id'] = $cart_item->id;
            $order_content[$key]['qty'] = $cart_item->qty;
        }



        foreach($order_content as $order_item)
        {
            $order->products()->sync([
                $order_item['id'] => ['qty' => $order_item['qty']]
            ]);
        }

Comment: Thank you! After your explanation and reading docs i've got it! Here's working version:

foreach($order_content as $order_item)
        {
             $order->products()->attach($order_item['product_id'],['qty'=>$order_item['qty'],'price'=>$order_item['price']]);
        }